# PTW and Klein wep crack algorithem

Tags: encryption, cryptography, wifi, wep, aircrack-ng

I am trying to understand the PTW and Klein algorithms for wep cracking and got stuck.
i am using this as reference: http://www.item.ntnu.no/_media/people/personalpages/phd/anton/kleins_and_ptw_attacks_on_wep.pdf
and got stuck on page 7:  Klein's Attack on WEP

According to this i should **assume** that i know the first 15 bytes of the data field. By using these 15 bytes i am able to calculate all needed variables for the key.
The 15 bytes helps me calculate X[i], but i only have the first 3 bytes(which are the IVs), so how do i calculate X if i don't know all the 15 first bytes of the data field

Maybe i will ask a little bit different:

According to what i can find on google, the first 15 bytes are pretty predictable because i know that the packets i have are ARP responses. The problem is that i don't understand what is so predicable about them?

**Edit:**:

I think i got the answer.
At appears that the first 16 bytes of an ARP response are always the same:

\xAA \xAA \x03 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x08 \x06 \x00 \x01 \x08 \x00 \x06 \x04 \x00 \x02

These are my missing 16 bytes of clear text.

Comment: Glad you've solved it yourself, but this is off topic here as it does not involve programming (try security.stackexchange.com next time)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: Note also that you should post answers as ... (drum roll) answers. Please do not edit in the answer in the question. This allows questions to be closed. Read the FAQ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got the answer. At appears that the first 16 bytes of an ARP response are always the same:

\xAA \xAA \x03 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x08 \x06 \x00 \x01 \x08 \x00 \x06 \x04 \x00 \x02

These are my missing 16 bytes of clear text.